# Google Fonts loading explained

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'd like to know, how google fonts finds out, which fonts to load. For example when I use this inside my CSS

```
@import '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300';
```

it returns a CSS that is interpreted immediately (the loading of this resource even blocks the browser rendering afaik):

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/0eC6fl06luXEYWpBSJvXCIX0hVgzZQUfRDuZrPvH3D8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Fl4y0QdOxyyTHEGMXX8kcYX0hVgzZQUfRDuZrPvH3D8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
// ...and some more
```

I always thought, when you provide a `url(...)` inside CSS, the browser loads this resource immediately.

However, when you open this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgkvEr and have a look at your network tab (maybe clear your cache) you can see that it loads exactly two resources: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300 and then http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2 which is the normal latin range (defined at the bottom of the loaded font css):

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

> So, does the browser look at what characters you use, and THEN load the used font? Or does it depend on your browser settings? I can't find any resource that documents this behaviour (or I'm searching for the wrong keyword). **I suspect it has something to do with the `unicode-range:` at the bottom of the CSS.**

Answer (score 3):

1. The browser reads the `@import` instruction which tells him to load this CSS page served by Google: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300. This page is loaded instantly.
2. In that page, there are some `url()` instructions which tell the browser where are the font files located. **The browser doesn't download these fonts until it needs them.** For example, if that font is never used by any element, the browser won't download it.

> I suspect it has something to do with the `unicode-range`: at the bottom of the CSS.

Yes, that's it. `unicode-range` specifies which class of characters does that font include (for example, cyrillic characters). If there aren't characters of that rage inside your page, those fonts won't be downloaded.

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

Comment: Another reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Browser performs page layout and determines which font variants are required to render specified text on the page.
> 2. For each required font the browser checks if the font is available locally.
> 3. If the file is not available locally, it iterates over external definitions:
>   - If a format hint is present the browser checks if it supports it before initiating the download, and otherwise advances to the next one.
>   - If no format hint is present, the browser downloads the resource.

[Google web font optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization)